# Jersey MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html

Tags: maven-2, thymeleaf, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

I am going to display html using "Thymeleaf", but the following errors are given.
The server using is tomcat8.
My code looks like.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.abc.def</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey_de</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jersey_de</name>

<build>
    <finalName>jersey_de</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- my setting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    
        Jersey Web Application
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        
            jersey.config.server.provider.packages
            com.abc.def.jersey_de
        
        
            com.abc.def.jersey_de.ThymeleafViewProcessor
            /WEB-INF/view/
        
        1
    
    
        Jersey Web Application
        /webapi/*

javacode

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

import com.abc.def.jersey_de.domain.TestPOJO;

@Path("top")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class DemoCtrl {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable getIt() {
        Viewable vb = new Viewable("test",new TestPOJO());
        System.out.println("top end");
        return vb;
    }
}
```

ThymeleafViewProcessor

```
@Provider
public class ThymeleafViewProcessor implements TemplateProcessor<String> {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    /**
     * コンストラクタ
     */
    public ThymeleafViewProcessor() {

        TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheTTLMs(3600000L);

        templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
        System.out.println("ThymeleafViewProcessor end");
    }

    /**
     * 参照させるファイル名を解決する。
     */
    @Override
    public String resolve(String name, MediaType mediaType) {

        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(String templateReference, Viewable viewable, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

        WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);

        //HTML内でモデルオブジェクトを使用できるようにしている。
        //ここはモデル名をそのまま使用できるようにした方が良い。
        context.setVariable("item", viewable.getModel());

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        templateEngine.process(templateReference, context, writer);

        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

ApplicationSetting

```
@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class ApplicationSetting extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationSetting() {

        packages(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());

        register(ThymeleafViewProcessor.class);
        register(MvcFeature.class);
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        System.out.println("ApplicationSetting ");
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand it.It makes original .I added a cord to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was settled.
The points that I revised are as follows.

web.xml

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.abc.def.jersey_de.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId><!-- 動きが変わらないので不要？ -->
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- 不要？ -->
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.21</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```